# .htaccess with same index

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rule

I have this url: `http://domain.com/?i=f` which is my forum page.
I wish to rewrite that to `http://domain.com/forum`

I do that like this:

```
RewriteRule ^forum ?i=f [L]
```

That works fine. But here comes the problem. Since it is a forum, it also have categories and topics. Therefore, I have this url: `http://domain.com/?i=f&p=t&cid=ID` which is the categories page.

I wish to rewrite that to: `http://domain.com/forum/cat/id`

But if I do it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^forum/cat/([^/]*)$ /?i=f&p=t&cid=$1 [L]
```

It doesn't work. The URL /forum/cat/ID cannot be loaded.

What would the actual rule be to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add **$** at the end of forum rule
Right now I have no apache installed

Comment: Which one of the rules? Like this: `RewriteRule ^forum ?i=f [L]$`